# How do I get a snapshot of the forgeviewer without markups

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

How can i get a snapshot of the viewer and save it separately as an image?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by combining the [Viewer3D#getScreenShot](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getscreenshot-w-h-cb-overlayrenderer) method and the `renderToCanvas` method of the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore` extension, like so:

```js
async function getScreenshotDataUrl(viewer, width, height) {
  const markupExt = await viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      markupExt.renderToCanvas(context, function () {
        resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
      });
    };
    viewer.getScreenShot(width, height, blob => image.src = blob);
  });
}
```

Here's a codepen demonstrating the above code: https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/gOMPYRV?editors=0010.

Comment: Hi , 
This gave me an error saying but managed to get it done using this https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/screenshot-markups. But how can save the image separately ?

Comment: If you want to store just the viewer snapshot, simply remove the `markupExt.renderToCanvas` method call and replace it with just `resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are only interested in an image of the markup, exclude the `image.onload` and `viewer.getScreenShot` altogether. Just create a canvas, get its context, call `markupExt.renderToCanvas`, and finally return the result with `resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));`.

Comment: Thank you @Petr, it worked for me . managed to get the blob URL .
Cheers