# Generate new PDF with SVG Markups

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg, autodesk-forge, itext7

I'm trying to generate a new PDF with the SVGs created with the extension Autodesk.PDF

```
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv'));
            viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
            viewer.start();

            viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then(() => {
                viewer.loadModel(path, viewer);
                viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore")
                viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui")
            });
        });
```

I can load the PDFs but after that I don't really know what to do.

Playing in the console, I managed to find that I can get a list of  and I can iterate over it and save if in a variable.

I'm using iTextSharp on the back-end to manage PDFs for my application, so would be good if I could use it to add the SVGs to the PDF, but I'm open to try another libs.

That's how I'm trying to add the SVG:

```
        var reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path))));
        var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
        var writer = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("newdoc.pdf")).SetSmartMode(true));
        pdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(1, 1, writer);
        //var appendedHtml = "<html><body>";
        var appendedHtml = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' baseProfile='full' layer-order-id='markups-svg' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: scale(1, -1); touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);' width='1105' height='690' viewBox='4.3959721282740105 4.558617165575239 30.58327865600586 19.097249984760307' pointer-events='painted' cursor='crosshair'><metadata><markup_document xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' data-model-version='4'></markup_document></metadata><g cursor='inherit' pointer-events='stroke' style='touch-action: manipulation; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);'><metadata><markup_element xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' stroke-width='2.7548209366391347' stroke-color='#ff0000' stroke-opacity='1' fill-color='#ff0000' fill-opacity='0' type='rectangle' position='22.89795796238312 13.271543227939889' size='14.605644607543944 10.309867361327829' rotation='0'></markup_element></metadata><path id='markup' d='M -5.925411835452405 -3.777523212344347 l 11.85082367090481 0 l 0 7.555046424688694 l -11.85082367090481 0 z' stroke-width='2.7548209366391347' stroke='rgba(255,0,0,1)' fill='none' transform='translate( 22.89795796238312 , 13.271543227939889 ) rotate( 0 )'/></g></svg>";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appendedHtml);
        SvgConverter.DrawOnDocument(new MemoryStream(bytes), writer, 1);
        pdfDocument.Close();
        writer.Close();
```

New PDF file is generated properly but without the SVG...

EDIT:
Apparently the style transform: scale(1, -1) is making my SVG disappear on the PDF, without it I can see the SVG but it's in the wrong position and the size is wrong too.

Left is the correct and right is after pass through my code
[image: image comparison]

Comment: iTextSharp does not support svg.

Comment: do you suggest any other library?

Comment: Maybe there is a workaround? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408042/vector-graphics-in-itext-pdf

Answer (score 0):

On the Forge side there isn't much we can help with I'm afraid. The `Autodesk.PDF` extension in Forge Viewer only supports *reading* PDFs, not *writing* them. What you *can* do is output the current view in Forge Viewer as a raster image, and draw the markup SVG into it (see [How do I get a snapshot of the forgeviewer without markups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352005/how-do-i-get-a-snapshot-of-the-forgeviewer-without-markups/64353026#64353026)).